# Multiple statement which includes special characters using if causing errors

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, test

I have been trying to write a script that will checks if the specific content is not found in specific files/folders then it should print "failed". else it should print "success". 
However, the following script causing multiple errors.

```
if [[ ( ! grep '/example.com' /opt/nfs &>/dev/null ) || ( ! grep -R '/example.com' /data &>/dev/null) ]]
then
echo "Failed"
else
echo "Passed"
fi
```

Can anyone tell me why it's causing errors and is there anyway to eliminate the errors and get the expected output?

UPDATE: I'm getting following errors:

```
s.sh: line 1: conditional binary operator expected
s.sh: line 1: expected `)'
s.sh: line 1: syntax error near `'/example.com''
s.sh: line 1: `if [[ ( ! grep '/example.com' /opt/nfs &>/dev/null ) || ( ! grep -R '/example.com' /data &>/dev/null) ]]'
```

Comment: what errors? ...

Comment: Hu @RomanPerekhrest, I have updated my question with errors. Thanks.

Comment: Most probably the use of & in the if statement. Also there is no need to redirect to /dev/null as you can use grep -q (quiet) instead

Comment: Read [Simple logical operators in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270440/simple-logical-operators-in-bash/6270803#6270803)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Straight-forward way:

```
grep -q '/example.com' /opt/nfs || grep -Rq '/example.com' /data
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then   # check exit status
    echo "Passed"
else 
    echo "Failed"
fi
```

---

- *grep*'s `-q` option tells do not write anything to standard output. Exit immediately with zero `0` status if any match is found, even if an error was detected.
- `$?` - contains *exit status* code of the last command run

---

The above could be also simplified to:

```
if grep -q '/example.com' /opt/nfs || grep -Rq '/example.com' /data; then
    echo "Passed"
else 
    echo "Failed"
fi
```

Comment: Working great. thank you so much for the explanation.

Comment: @BuvaneshKumar, you're welcome

Comment: `[ $? -eq 0 ]` is a bit pointless as a command. That's a command that returns a 0 exit status if the previous exit status was 0. Doing `if grep....` directly would make more sense.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, you have my note

Answer (score 5):

`[[...]]` is a construct used to perform comparisons and other sorts of tests. It's a `ksh` command whose parsing follows special syntax rules and replaces the `[` standard command (with normal simple command parsing).

Here, it's of no use. It's whether `grep` the `grep` command succeeds that you want to test (not a `[[...]]` or `[` command), so it's just:

```
if grep -qF /example.com /opt/nfs || grep -RqF /example.com /data
then echo passed
else echo failed
fi
```

`-q` suppresses the output and also optimises by exiting as soon as one match is found instead of trying to find all matches.

Comment: Hi  @StéphaneChazelas I would like to try this in a reverse way as follows " if ! grep -q /example.com /opt/nfs || ! grep -Rq /example.com /data
then echo failed
else echo passed
fi" But I didn't get expected output. Is there any wrong with above reverse script?

Comment: @BuvaneshKumar, are you sure it's a `||` and not a `&&` that you meant? Do you want /example.com to be found in neither /opt/nfs nor /data (`&&`) or either not found in `/opt/nfs` or not found in `data` (`||`)? `! { A || B; }` is `! A && ! B`

Comment: I am sure, it's a | | and not a &&.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a possible simplification of your solution:

- First of all, if you are using GNU `grep`, it can search in multiple file|folders provided in argument line. So basically no need to launch two `grep` command for looking to the same pattern in two different folders : `grep '/example.com' /opt/nfs /data` does the job for searching occurence of **/example.com** in those two folders.
- Second two negations equal a positive. So why not simply use this code : 
  `if grep -rq "/example.com" /opt/nfs /data ; then echo "success" ; else echo "failed" ; fi`
  `grep` will be successfull if it finds occurence of "/example.com" either in `/opt/nfs` or in `/data`

It will be faster, and more efficient, only one `grep` spawned from the shell.

Comment: Good point. (note that all greps  can search in multiple files, it's not just GNU  grep; however -r/-R was initially a GNU grep feature and depending on the version both are not necessarily the same).

Comment: I was not sure about others `grep` i only have Gnu version at hand.

Comment: After looking again at the OP and my solution, i conclude my solution is not valid. The OP only succeed if /example.com is present in both folder /opt/nfs and /data, it fails in all other situation. grep is unable to handle that in one invocation.

Answer (score 2):

Try like this:

```
if [[ ! $(grep '/example.com' /opt/nfs &>/dev/null) || ! $(grep -R '/example.com' /data &>/dev/null) ]]
then
echo "Failed"
else
echo "Passed"
fi
```

But i think your script does not make sense because you suppress `stdout` and `stderr` with `&>/dev/null`. The output of your `grep` command always will be empty. Replace `&` to `2` to suppress `stderr` only.